# Java - [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

I had a java app with mysql connection but i had to transfer my database to sqlite from mysql because of mysql can not be embedded, i have the connection but i get this exception when i am using the app.

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
```

I learnt this is a common mistake but i tried most of the answers however couldn't solve. The problem is i have about 30 different methods with void type or return types like these 2 for example below; (I call these methods on my swing app later)

I have these at start of my class;

```
private Connection con = null;
private Statement statement = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedstatement = null;
```

Methods for example;

```
public int lastPlaceProgram(){

    String query= "Select * from userprogram where laststayed = 1";
    try {
        statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        int programid = 0;
        while(rs.next()){
            programid = rs.getInt("programid");
        }
        return programid;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Operations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

or

```
public String programType(int programid){
    String query = "Select * from programs where id = ?";
    try {
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, programid);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        String type = "";
        while(rs.next()){

            type = rs.getString("type");
        }
        return type;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Operations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }

}
```

And constructor;

```
public Operations() {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C://Users//Me//Desktop//sqlited/trying.db";
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Operations.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

I tried to add these finally block to after catch blocks of all my 30 methods;

```
finally{
    try{
      con.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

But it didn't work, it gave Connection is closed mistake this time. I also tried to add preparedstatement.close(); to this finally block but didn't still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally blocks didn't work for me, i closed them manually if i had that variable to close. I mean if i used ResultSet and PreparedStatement at a method then i made rs.close() and preparedstatement.close() just before catch or before return. If i just had Preparedstatement variable on the method then i just did preparedstatement.close() before catch block or before return.